RelatvieLayout's centerInParent doesn't work right with WindowInsetPadding
I set the centerInParent option to true for rl_container, which has a parent RelativeLayout.
but even though the width and height of rl_container are match_parent, it doesn't fill the screen as shown in the picture.What I expected was for rl_container to fill the screen. Is there a way to keep centerInParent as true and make it fill the screen?
Here is my code:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.mama)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
    }
}

My Layout is here:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mama"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#329ba8" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:background="@color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>

I tried setting the padding and margin of rl_container to 0dp, but it didn't work.
I noticed that @+id/rl_background's y is 50dp but @+id/rl_container's y is 37dp. (I checked on Layout inspector)

Edited
It's not an XML issue. Just change your MainActivity.kt file  ViewCompact.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(...){...} code.
Change sysyemBars.top to 0.
After that, your code looks like this.
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.mama)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, 0, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
     }
}


Thanks for the comment. I implemented that code because I wanted my app to look the same as before while enabling EdgeToEdge, so I don't think I should remove that code.

Okay. Just set the padding of the top to 0. I just edited my answer.

Unfortunately, your code doesn't work. Even when i implement it like that, the views don't overlap.

Bro, I tried this code before sharing it here. The code works fine on my device.
